# Unix shell user input phone number

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to write a script so that it will check whether the user has entered a valid phone number and then check against a `records.txt` file.

I have the following code. However when I enter a phone number it does not recognize it.

I am also not sure how to implement a check against the text file?

```
echo "Enter a phone number as XXXXXXXX: "
read phoneNumber
while [ "$phoneNumber" != [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]
    do
    echo "Please enter a phone number as XXXXXXXX: "
    read phoneNumber
done
echo $$phoneNumber
pause
```

Comment: Do you have eight digit phone numbers?

Comment: Yes we do. After I enter a phone number it says "Please enter a phone number as XXXXXXXX: " the while loop.  It does not recognise the eight digits as a valid entry. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: What is your shebang line and are you on debian or ubuntu?

Comment: My shebang line is #!/bin/sh.  I am running Ubuntu @ElliottFrisch

Comment: It's important to note that on Ubuntu [`/bin/sh`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) is dash (and not bash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your regex in a variable like so: `pat="[0-9]{8}"`.

The phrase `{8}` means 8 repetitions of the previous character set.

In this case, the "previous character set" is anything in the range `[0-9]`.

Then write your `while` condition using the two variables you've created:

```
while [[ ! $phoneNumber =~ $pat ]]
```

Notice the added `!` to the start, to negate the expression in brackets.

When evaluating regular expressions like this, we use double square brackets `[[ expression ]]` as well as `=~` to test matching.

Comment: After adding that I get the following error.   ./testing.sh: 6: ./testing.sh: [[: not found @Travis

Comment: Oh I see, you're not using bash. Use `/bin/bash` and my code should work :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to include start and end anchors in your regex if you want to validate phone numbers of exactly 8 digits or otherwise, it would accept the numbers which has more than 8 digits.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter a phone number as XXXXXXXX: "
read phoneNumber
pat="^[0-9]{8}$"
while [[ ! $phoneNumber =~ $pat ]]
    do
    echo "Please enter a phone number as XXXXXXXX: "
    read phoneNumber
done
echo $phoneNumber
```